# Terminating thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I've a dialog displaying progress bar + some other data, and I also have a cancel button on this dialog. While this dialog is displayed there is potentially heavy computation going on, which is show on progress bar. This computation is started from withing this dialog code so I have:

```
Counting_Progress_Dialog::Counting_Progress_Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);
    thread_ = new Threaded;//THIS IS THE THREAD IN WHICH COMPUTATION IS BEING PERFORMED
    connect(thread_,SIGNAL(counter_value(int)),this,SLOT(update_progress_bar(int)));
    connect(this,SIGNAL(rejected()),thread_,SLOT(terminate()),Qt::QueuedConnection);//  
HERE I'M CONNECTING REJECTED ON DIALOG TO TERMINATE ON THREAD

}



   void Counting_Progress_Dialog::start()
    {

        thread_->start(QThread::LowestPriority);

    }
```

and I do invoke this in part of the program:

```
void My_Class::dummy_()
{
    auto old_priority = this->thread()->priority();
    this->thread()->setPriority(QThread::HighestPriority);
    Counting_Progress_Dialog progress;

    progress.start();//this will start thread
    progress.exec();//this will enter it's event loop
    progress.wait();//this will wait until thread is finished
    this->thread()->setPriority(QThread::NormalPriority);
}
```

But despite all this, when I press cancel on my dialog, the whole application freezes. What am I doing wrong? How to make it behave correctly?

UPDATED:

```
void Counting_Progress_Dialog::wait()
{
    thread_->wait();
}
```

Comment: 1. You should not be setting priorities. That's just asking for trouble. Stop doing that! 2. How do you handle the cancel operation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my cancel operation is shown as a last connection

Comment: Terminating a thread from another thread is unsafe and bad practice. Better set a "cancel" flag, let the thread's code check for the flag and terminate by itself it is set.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are connecting using 2 different strategies. But if `thread_` and `this`(counting dialog) are really within two separated threads then the connection will always be `Qt::QueuedConnection`. Well that's not the issue.

```
progress.exec();//this will enter it's event loop
```

Calling exec() suspend the execution of `dummy_()` until the dialog have to return. And when the dialog return your thread is terminated. So I don't see the purpose of

```
progress.wait();//this will wait until thread is finished
```

By the way which function is that? the only one I know is `Qthread::wait()`. I am pretty confident the issue is here...

***edit:*** 
progress.wait() is not the issue... But it is possible that the events sent by the thread are causing trouble in some way. Use the debugger or some qDebug() to see if `update_progress_bar` is called after you push cancel.

Comment: progress.wait is simply wrapper for thread::wait, which means that wait on thread started in this dialog is called